# Matlab - Image Processing - Extracting Contour

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to MATLAB and new to image processing.

I am going to find the contour of an image, so

```
leaf = imread('images\leaf.jpg')
SE = [1 1 1
      1 1 1
      1 1 1]
figure
imshow(leaf)
title("leaf_origin")

erosed_leaf = imerode(leaf,SE);
Contour = double(leaf) - double(erosed_leaf)
Contour=~Contour
figure
imshow(Contour)
```

This gives me an error while running `imshow`

> Error using images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 119)
>   If input is logical (binary), it must be two-dimensional.
>
> Error in images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams (line 27)
>   common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);
>
> Error in images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs (line 78)
>   common_args = images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);
>
> Error in imshow (line 241)
>   images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs({'Parent','Border','Reduce'},preparsed_varargin{:});

if I remove `~` in front of `contour`, it works but gives incorrect output. Can anybody give me any hint about the error?

Comment: before this line, `Contour=~Contour` variable Contour is a 3-dimensional array of doubles, which I assume represents colour. After executing`Contour=~Contour` variable Contour becomes a 3-dimensional logical array (i e filled with 1 and 0) and function `imshow` does not know what to do with this input, hence the error you get. What are you trying to achieve with `Contour=~Contour`? revert colours?

Comment: @ArtyomEmelyanenko yes, revert colours. Thanks for the help. After change the logic array to double array, it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
erosed_leaf = imerode(leaf,SE);
contour = double(leaf) - double(erosed_leaf);
contour = double(~contour);

figure();
imshow(contour);
```